# How did Rutherford estimate 1/20000 alpha particles reflected?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, atomic-physics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

As we know in Rutherfords gold foil experiment, Rutherford shot decayed alpha particles into a very thin sheet of gold foil, and after many trials looking into a telescope they observed that about 1 in 20000 alpha particles bounced off this "concentrated, positively charged nucleus' more than 90 degrees. Since they were using the naked eye and with a microscope counting the light beams from the ZnS screen, ***is this a pure estimate or is there an actual mathematical formula to deduce this number?***

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to realize is that the canonical 'Rutherford scattering' experiment was not some one-off thing. I realize that could be the impression from introductory textbooks, since they only discuss that one experiment. Instead, that result came out of years of research in the Rutherford group to discover the properties and effects of what Marie Curie called 'radium emanations' when she announced it in 1898.

Four key papers to consider are:

On the Scattering of the $\alpha$-Particles by Matter, H. Geiger, Proceedings of the Royal Society, Volume 81, Issue 546 p. 174-177 (1908). Here they were investigating how the beam of $\alpha$ particles spread out as they went through more and more material (gold leafs as it turns out, as well as air). They only looked in the forward direction, measuring the angular spread.

On a Diffuse Reflection of the $\alpha$-Particles, H. Geiger and E. Marsden, Proceedings of the Royal Society, Volume 82, Issue 557, p. 495-500 (1909). Here they were motivated by the, even at that time well known, fact that $\beta$ particles (electrons) do reflect backwards off of material. It was not anticipated that $\alpha$ particles would necessarily do the same, particularly given the previous paper that showed much smaller angular spreads then obtained from $\beta$ particles. But, as good experimentalists do, if you "know" what the result will be, you'd better perform the experiment. And, they saw the unanticipated backscattering.

The Scattering of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ Particles by Matter and the Structure of the Atom, E. Rutherford, London, Edinburgh and Dublin Philosophical Magazine, Volume 21, Issue 125 (1911). Here Rutherford derives his scattering formula, applicable to all $1/r^{2}$ potentials, and shows that the Geiger-Marsden experiment of 1909 directly indicates a very small, nearly point-like nucleus and $\alpha$ particle.

The Laws of Deflexion of $\alpha$ Particles through Large Angles, H. Geiger and E. Marsden, London, Edinburgh and Dublin Philosophical Magazine, volume 25 Issue 148, p. 604-623 (1913). This paper is more or less the experimental test of Rutherford's formula, measuring angular variation off of different amounts of different elements. A very nice series of experiments all in all.

The point is, if you read about an experiment in a textbook it might seem like one single event, but in reality they are part of a larger body of work. The group was well aware of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ particles, were doing a wide variety of experiments trying different things with *both* kinds of particles, and had built up substantial understanding of issues like the number of $\alpha$ particles they were getting, how to change the number of $\alpha$ particles per second experimentally, the effects of air or thin foils (mica, gold, lead, ...) on $\alpha$ propagation, etc. They did not walk in to the lab one day and perform the Rutherford scattering experiment without any background whatsoever. They had a smooth running, well-oiled laboratory performing many experiments for many years.

So, how did they know only one out of many $\alpha$ particles bounced back? They had long experience running experiments with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ particles and knew how to get the numbers right.

Answer (score 1):

[This article describes](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/252/Rutherford_Scattering/Rutherford_Scattering.html) the original experiment.

> While at McGill University, he had discovered that the radioactive element thorium emitted a gas which was itself radioactive, but if the gas radioactivity was monitored separately from the thorium's, he found it decreased geometrically, losing approximately half its current strength for each minute that passed. The gas he had found was a short-lived isotope of radon, and this was the first determination of a "half-life" for a radioactive material. (Pais, IB, page 120) .

So he knew by formulas at the time the original mass and the number of decay products. He got the nobel in 1908 for this discovery.

The scattering experiments started in 1909.

> To quote Rutherford (a lecture he gave much later):
>
> "I had observed the scattering of alpha-particles, and Dr. Geiger in my laboratory had examined it in detail. He found, in thin pieces of heavy metal, that the scattering was usually small, of the order of one degree. One day Geiger came to me and said, "Don't you think that young Marsden, whom I am training in radioactive methods, ought to begin a small research?" Now I had thought that, too, so I said, " Why not let him see if any alpha-particles can be scattered through a large angle?" I may tell you in confidence that I did not believe that they would be, since we knew the alpha-particle was a very fast, massive particle with a great deal of energy, and you could show that if the scattering was due to the accumulated effect of a number of small scatterings, the chance of an alpha-particle's being scattered backward was very small. Then I remember two or three days later Geiger coming to me in great excitement and saying "We have been able to get some of the alpha-particles coming backward …" It was quite the most incredible event that ever happened to me in my life. It was almost as incredible as if you fired a 15-inch shell at a piece of tissue paper and it came back and hit you."

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this experiment, there was no formula to use. This number is an estimate based their observations.